# Tips on generating dynamic form fields from a string of data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

So here's what I want to do.  I want to take a list of phrases, and in certain parts of the phrases, indicate that user input is required.. be it a dropdown list, a textbox, a date field, etc.  Kind of like Madlibs in a way.. but with the option of selecting things from a list.

For example:

> I own a `?list_of_cars?`, I purchased it on `?date?`.  It has `?freetext?`
>   miles on it.

This string gets broken apart into a mixture of text and HTML form fields/ASP.net controls.

`?list_of_cars?` gets turned into a dropdown list with a few options to choose from.

`?date?` gets turned into a date field (custom user control I created)

`?freetext?` is simply a textbox that the user can enter information into.

I have about 50 of these phrases that I need to work with.  The end result is that they will end up being plain text in a textbox after the user fills out the required input.

No lists need a large number of options.. cars was kind of a bad example.  The most options a list would contain would be 5 probably.

At this point, I started storing the entire string with a number of delimiters and placeholders into a database table.

For example, one row looks like this:

> I own a `{list^Nissan,Ford,Chevy}`, I purchased it on `{date}`. It has `{text}` miles on it.

Then I break it down and replace the placeholders with form fields.. then put it all back together into pure text.  I feel like there might be a smarter/better way to do this.  I'm not opposed to backing up and changing how the initial phrases are stored.

Just curious if anyone might have any tips/suggestions?

Comment: I'd start by considering how to separate pieces parts.  How about a field name, some sort of type, and perhaps some formatting info.  `{Car Make|list:carmake|n/a}` might be field with a prompt of `Car Make`, choices come from a dropdown list in a table, if NULL output "n/a".  A table with all list choices could contain the list selector ("carmake"), choice rank (1, 2, 3, ...) and choice ("Saab", "Unimog", "Volvo", ...).  In many forms you need to allow for multiple occurrences of a type, e.g. billing ZIP and shipping ZIP.  Ponder handling plurals, too: `{Dogs|int:dog:dogs|lonely}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some details for different aspects you’ll have to think of

**Storing lists**

I’d suggest you create two tables List (ListID, ListName) and ListItem (ListID, ItemName) and keep this data in database for the sake of easier maintenance. If you have several lists of cars that are equal that you need to update later this will make things easy for you.  On the other hand updating several strings is not as easy as this.

**Tags**

These need to be made so that they are easy to parse. I’d avoid complex names such as “{list^Nissan,Ford,Chevy}” and define this as ?list_ID?. All tags need to be easily identifiable. Maybe ?tag_name? is not a good idea because you’ll have questions marks that might make parsing more difficult. Better to use something like #!tag_name!#

**ASP.NET**

All controls need to be added to OnInit method, not later in the Page_Load.

**Parsing**

Here is something to get you started but it needs more work.

```
private const string OPEN_TAG = "!#";
private const string CLOSE_TAG = "#!";

private void Parse(string s)
{        
    int tagOpenIndex = 0;
    int tagCloseIndex = 0;

    tagOpenIndex = s.IndexOf(OPEN_TAG);

    string tag = string.Empty;

    while (tagOpenIndex >= 0)
    { 
        //Write everything before current tag opening 
        Response.Write(s.Substring(tagCloseIndex, tagOpenIndex));

        //Find where current tag is closing 
        tagCloseIndex = s.IndexOf(CLOSE_TAG, tagOpenIndex);

        //Get tag name
        tag = s.Substring(tagOpenIndex, tagCloseIndex - tagOpenIndex + 1);

        //Parse tag and create asp.net controls. Let's say this is a text box
        //You'll need to figure out where to put this and such
        //And also how to keep track of different control IDs so you can use these later.
        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t.ID = "Generate some ID";
        Form.Controls.Add(t);

        //Get the index of next open tag
        tagOpenIndex = s.IndexOf(OPEN_TAG, tagCloseIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer because of your method of scanning through the phrase string, thank you.  I was initially using `Regex.Split` but I like your method better.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow a similar approach to yours, but your create a control that had could read the Type of the Editor and also the available values.

And also i would store them separated using the String.Format like, this way you could re-use

So i would have a class with two properties

```
class RequiredInput
{
    public property string Phrase { get; set;}
    public property Field[] Fields { get; set;}
}

class Field
{
    public Type Type { get; set;}
    public object Default { get; set;}
    public object[] options { get; set;}
}
```

Then i would write down the parser on something like this:

```
var sentence = new RequiredInput();
sentence.Phrase = "I own a {0}, I purchased it on {1}. It has {2} miles on it.";
sentece.options = new Field[] { 
    new field(typeof(ComboBox), new string[] { "Car1", "Car2", "Car3"}),
    new field(typeof(DateEdit), DateTime.Now),
    new field(typeof(TextEdit), String.Empty) }
}
```

I dont know, just thinking....